# merging two very similar git repositories

Tags: git, merge

Is there anyway to merge two git repositories that have many of the same files without having tons of false positive conflicts?

For example:
A long time ago, repoB was "forked" from repoA back on SVN.  repoA was moved to a git repository, than repoB was moved to a seperate git repository. Now, I want to merge the changes from repoB back into repoA, but just pushing repoB onto repoA results in almost every file in conflict even if the files were the same between the two. Rebasing repoB onto repoA results in the same conflicts. Is there a way to merge these two repositories without having to resolving hundreds of conflicts?

History doesn't matter.

Comment: If files same conflict should be solved automatically. It's not on your repos?

Comment: May be [How do you merge two git repositories?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6316468/1705441) is the right approach in your case.